# Border-Top Property inconsistency with Safari 5.1

Tags: css, safari

I'm currently working on this site:

http://tweeds.workofjonas.com

The green triangle that comes down as you scroll is made up of two triangles that have these properties:

```
border-top: 5000px solid #398C00;
border-left: 2880.00018px solid transparent;

border-top: 5000px solid #398C00;
border-right: 2880.00018px solid transparent;
```

This works fine in all browsers (including Safari 6.x) except for Safari 5.1, where the '5000px' border-top-width is interpreted as a lower number.  Bumping this property up to a number like 8191px in Safari 5.1 is more accurate.

Really stuck on this one. I've tried using 'ems' as well, but to no avail.  Any help would be much appreciated.